# Can't use the nested_form_for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-form-for

I am using the [nested_form_for gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for the first time. I don't know if this is an issue or if I am using it wrong, but I am getting an "undefined method nested_form_for" error.
I have a pretty regular form as you can see:

```
  <%= nested_form_for @user do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :godfathers do |godfather_form| %>
            <%=  godfather_form.label :name %> <br/>
            <%=  godfather_form.text_field :name %> <br/>
            <%=  godfather_form.label :description %> <br/>
            <%=  godfather_form.text_field :description %> <br/>
            <%=  godfather_form.link_to_remove "Remove this godfather" %>
        <% end %>
       <%= f.link_to_add "Add a godfather", :godfathers %>
   <% end %>
```

By the way, I installed the gem and ran the: `rails generate nested_form:install command` to generate the nested_form.js file that I included in my layout after the jquery inclusion(`<%= javascript_include_tag :default, 'nested_form' %>`).

Anyone using this gem as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Everything looks right and if the generator ran the gem should be in place. Have you restarted your server since adding the plugin to your Gemfile?

Comment: Can't believe I have spent so many hours trying to figure out what was wrong...I probably need a plugin that reminds me to restart my server every time I install a gem! Anyway, thank you!